# Access cursor by column name dynamically

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-cursor

Can I access a cursor's column dynamically? I mean by name? something like this:

```
declare
 v_cursor := select * from emp;
begin
 FOR reg IN v_cursor LOOP
   dbms_output.put_line(**reg['column_name_as_string']**);
 end loop;
end;
```

I know the bold part **is not** PL/SQL, but I'm looking for something like that and can't find it anywhere.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the package [`DBMS_SQL`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_sql.htm#ARPLS68257) to create and access cursors with dynamic queries.

However it's not really straightforward to access a column by name because the `DBMS_SQL` package uses positioning and in a dynamic query we may not know the order of the columns before the execution.

Furthermore, in the context of this question, it appears that we may not know which column we want to display at compile time, we will assume that the column we want to display is given as a parameter.

We can use [`DBMS_SQL.describe_columns`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_sql.htm#ARPLS68257) to analyze the columns of a `SELECT` query after it has been parsed to build a dynamic mapping of the columns. We will assume that all columns can be cast into `VARCHAR2` since we want to display them with `DBMS_OUTPUT`.

Here's an example:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE display_query_column(p_query VARCHAR2,
  2                                                   p_column VARCHAR2) IS
  3     l_cursor            INTEGER;
  4     l_dummy             NUMBER;
  5     l_description_table dbms_sql.desc_tab3;
  6     TYPE column_map_type IS TABLE OF NUMBER INDEX BY VARCHAR2(32767);
  7     l_mapping_table column_map_type;
  8     l_column_value  VARCHAR2(4000);
  9  BEGIN
 10     l_cursor := dbms_sql.open_cursor;
 11     dbms_sql.parse(l_cursor, p_query, dbms_sql.native);
 12     -- we build the column mapping
 13     dbms_sql.describe_columns3(l_cursor, l_dummy, l_description_table);
 14     FOR i IN 1 .. l_description_table.count LOOP
 15        l_mapping_table(l_description_table(i).col_name) := i;
 16        dbms_sql.define_column(l_cursor, i, l_column_value, 4000);
 17     END LOOP;
 18     -- main execution loop
 19     l_dummy := dbms_sql.execute(l_cursor);
 20     LOOP
 21        EXIT WHEN dbms_sql.fetch_rows(l_cursor) <= 0;
 22        dbms_sql.column_value(l_cursor, l_mapping_table(p_column), l_column_value);
 23        dbms_output.put_line(l_column_value);
 24     END LOOP;
 25     dbms_sql.close_cursor(l_cursor);
 26  END;
 27  /

Procedure created
```

We can call this procedure with a query known only at run-time:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> exec display_query_column('SELECT * FROM scott.emp WHERE rownum < 5', 'ENAME');
SMITH
ALLEN
WARD
JONES

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed

SQL> exec display_query_column('SELECT * FROM scott.emp WHERE rownum < 5', 'EMPNO');
7369
7499
7521
7566

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed
```

Use caution with dynamic SQL: it has the same privileges as the user and can therefore execute any DML **and DDL** statement allowed for this schema.

For instance, the above procedure could be used to create or drop a table:

```
SQL> exec display_query_column('CREATE TABLE foo(id number)', '');
begin display_query_column('CREATE TABLE foo(id number)', ''); end;
ORA-01003: aucune instruction analysée
ORA-06512: à "SYS.DBMS_SQL", ligne 1998
ORA-06512: à "APPS.DISPLAY_QUERY_COLUMN", ligne 13
ORA-06512: à ligne 1

SQL> desc foo
Name Type   Nullable Default Comments 
---- ------ -------- ------- -------- 
ID   NUMBER Y
```

Comment: Maybe you could add 2 lines of example. I mean, answering question by "RTFM" isn't the example driven approach as stackoverflow established its reputation by :)

Comment: @Edgar I agree, but it's quite difficult to build a small example with `DBMS_SQL` since it's not very user-friendly. Still, I've updated my answer, hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

It's probably easiest to make the query dynamic if you can.

```
DECLARE
  v_cursor  SYS_REFCURSOR;
  dynamic_column_name VARCHAR2(30) := 'DUMMY';
  column_value  VARCHAR2(32767);
BEGIN
  OPEN v_cursor FOR 'SELECT ' || dynamic_column_name || ' FROM dual';
  LOOP
    FETCH v_cursor INTO column_value;
    EXIT WHEN v_cursor%NOTFOUND;
    dbms_output.put_line( column_value );
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE v_cursor;
END;
```

If you really want to have a hardcoded `SELECT *` and dynamically select a column from that by name, I think you could do that using DBMS_SQL as Vincent suggests, but it will be somewhat more complex.

Answer (score 1):

You mean something like:

```
declare
  cursor sel_cur is
  select * from someTable;

begin
  for rec in sel_cur
  loop
    dbms_output.put_line('col1: ' || rec.col1);
  end loop;
end;
```

Comment: No, 'cause the rec.col1 is hardcoded there. I need to programmatically access rec's fields, by column name. like: rec['col1'] or something like that.